# Getting all file sizes on a SharePoint 2013 server

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-designer

How do I get all the files in my SharePoint 2013 server?   It will list the document libraries but the .csv will have no information printed on it.

I am able to run this fine on SharePointOnline and it will print the information in the .csv file.

Thanks for any assistance!

```
#Config Variables
$SiteURL = "https://sharepoint.com/"
$CSVFilePath="C:\Users\user\Desktop\file.csv"

Import-Module SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline
Connect-PnpOnline -Url $SiteURL -Credential $cred

 
 
#Get all document libraries
$FileData = @()
$DocumentLibraries = Get-PnPList | Where-Object {$_.BaseType -eq "DocumentLibrary" -and $_.Hidden -eq $False}
 
#Iterate through document libraries
ForEach ($List in $DocumentLibraries)
{
    Write-host "Processing Library:"$List.Title -f Yellow
     
    #Get All Files of the library with size > 100MB
    #$Files = Get-PnPListItem -List $List -PageSize 500 | Where {($_.FieldValues.FileLeafRef -like "*.*") -and ($_.FieldValues.SMTotalFileStreamSize/1MB -gt 100)}
    if($Files.BaseType -eq "DocumentLibrary")  
    {
        #Collect data from each files
        ForEach ($File in $Files)
        {
            $FileData += [PSCustomObject][ordered]@{
                Library         = $List.Title
                FileName        = $File.FieldValues.FileLeafRef
                URL              = $File.FieldValues.FileRef
                Size            = [math]::Round(($File.FieldValues.SMTotalFileStreamSize/1MB),2)
            }
        }
    }
}
#Export Files data to CSV File
$FileData | Sort-object Size -Descending
$FileData | Export-Csv -Path $CSVFilePath -NoTypeInformation


#Read more: https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2018/11/sharepoint-online-find-all-large-files-using-powershell.html#ixzz6Yy8ueFyy
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SharePoint 2013, not seeing property "**SMTotalFileStreamSize**",
you may try **File_x0020_Size** instead

**This worked for me (partial script)**

```
#Get all document libraries
$FileData = @()
$DocumentLibraries = Get-PnPList | Where-Object {$_.BaseType -eq "DocumentLibrary" -and $_.Hidden -eq $False}
 
#Iterate through document libraries
ForEach ($List in $DocumentLibraries)
{
    Write-host "Processing Library:"$List.Title -f Yellow
     
    #Get All Files of the library with size > 100MB
    $Files = Get-PnPListItem -List $List # -PageSize 500 | Where {($_.FieldValues.FileLeafRef -like "*.*") -and ($_.FieldValues.SMTotalFileStreamSize/1MB -gt 100)}

    #if($Files.BaseType -eq "DocumentLibrary")  
    #{
        #Collect data from each files
        ForEach ($File in $Files)
        {
            $FileData += [PSCustomObject][ordered]@{
                Library         = $List.Title
                FileName        = $File.FieldValues.FileLeafRef
                URL              = $File.FieldValues.FileRef
                Size            = $File.FieldValues.File_x0020_Size
            }
        }
    #}
}


#Export Files data to CSV File
$FileData | Sort-object Size -Descending
$FileData | Export-Csv -Path $CSVFilePath -NoTypeInformation
```

How property **File_x0020_Size** can be found:

[image]

Comment: I’ll give it a shot later this evening. Thanks. How about file names and url?  It isn’t recognizing it either.

Comment: That was exactly what I needed, thank you!  How did you determine the property was File_x0020_Size?  Is there a way to seach through the filter?

Comment: Glad to know that it helped. I found the property from intellisense in PS ISE. After completing the "ForEach" loop, the variables of the last iteration are still alive, so you can check the values. Posted a screenshot on this..